# How can I update any field value through VBA code in ms access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

How can I update any field value through VBA code in ms access? When I enter values in combobox, some of the fields in the relevant tables are updated as I enter the data. Whereas others do not. What should I do to solve this problem?

In a combobox I used me.refresh command and it is updating data as I enter. Whereas in another combobox I did the same, but I got no result. Where I am making mistakes?

Further is unregistered software did such problems so that they behave different at different times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you change a value of a textbox/combo box/etc on a form the record in the table is not immediately updated.  The default way Access handles it is to wait until the record no longer has focus and then it updates the record in the table with any changes you made.

If you want to, you can force an update to the record in the table via the After Update event by using the following:

```
Private Sub txtMyFieldName_AfterUpdate()
  Me.Dirty = False
End Sub
```

However, I would only do this when editing an existing record.  If you are entering a new record then you don't want to trigger `Me.Dirty = False` after every control has been updated.  If you do trigger `Me.Dirty = False` on new record entry and you have required fields that haven't been filled in yet, you will get an error stating that a required field cannot contain a null value.

Comment: i am unable to understand your last sentence please. if i am entering new record then what should i do.

Comment: ALSO after_update event should work  for  both bound and unbound controls ?

Comment: Unbound controls will not have any database fields to update.  So, `Me.Dirty = False` does not do anything for unbound controls.  But, you wouldn't need it to.  Unbound controls are controlled via an action to another control or user interaction.

Answer (score 3):

There is a slight conceptual difference between the change of a (bound) control's value on a form and the update of the underlying field's value. The underlying field's value might not be updated before the 'update' event is fired.

And, of course, if the control you are dealing with is unbound, there cannot be any field update ...

Edit:

If you want to change an unbound control value programmatically:

```
myForm.controls(myControl).value = "whatever"
```

**If you want to change a bound control and its underlying field, working on the field side**

```
myForm.recordset.fields(myField).value = "whatever" 
myForm.recordset.update
```

*You might then need to refresh your control on the screen so it displays the updated value*

**And on the control side**

```
myForm.controls(myControl).value = "whatever"
```

*You might then need to fire the update programmatically (recordset.update)event on your underlying control*

Comment: so how do i update any unbound control when lostfocus event fired.

Comment: As far as I remember, it depends how you are loosing the focus: if it's through ESC key, update might not be fired. If it's through Enter or TAB, it will be fired. Add some debug.print messages to your event and before/after update procedures and check how the different eventas are managed. I think you can also find some help on event hierarchy.